# How exactly does argc work when I don't use quotation marks?

Tags: c, program-entry-point, argc

My code is very simple :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints `17` after I input

```
./a.out 1 2 3 + *
```

Shouldn't it print `6` instead? The program's behavior is as expected if I put `''` around every argument except `./a.out`. This is strange, because I can use some programs with flags without using quotation marks(`''`, `""`).

Comment: Linux deals with the `*` argument in its own way. It does not reach the program. I suggest you print out all the 17 arguments given.

Comment: This is really more of a shell question than a C question.

Comment: `+` isn't special to the shell. The only specials that need to be quoted at listed in 2.2 here: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html

Comment: Replace `./a.out` with `echo` and you'll see what the arguments are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't quote or escape `*`, it's expanded as a wildcard by the shell when forming the program arguments. It's replaced with all the names in the current directory (except the ones that begin with `.`).

You must have had 12 files and subdirectories in your directory when you ran this.

Comment: Might have had fewer than 12 if some had spaces in their names

Comment: @stark No, the expansion of a wildcard does not undergo word splitting.